# What is a word for changing yourself to reflect the changing world?

Tags: vocabulary

What is a word for changing yourself to reflect the changing world? I'm looking for something else other than update and its synonyms, since they don't quite fully seem to explain what I want to say.

Comment: One candidate would be ***adapting***.

Comment: **Evolving** is also a possibility.

Comment: ***Adapting*** is probably what you want, but in the case where it's a drastic, sudden change provoked by circumstances, ***remaking*** might also be appropriate.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee: Indeed. But putting aside issues concerning *inheritance of acquired characteristics*, I'd say we usually think of even metaphorical ***evolution*** as representing inter-generational change (or at least, a *very slow* process). But a single individual could ***adapt*** quite quickly to changed circumstances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Completely disagree with your assessment of _evolving_. [Dictionary definitions include](http://wordnik.com/words/evolve): _gain through experience; become developed; develop or achieve gradually, as in: evolve a style of one's own_. [Situations can evolve](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22situation+is+evolving%22&safe=active&tbm=nws). [Careers evolve](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=%22career+evolved%22). Characters evolve (from a book review: _We watch Elizabeth Bennet evolve from a naïve young teenager into a savage slayer of the undead_).

Comment: Does it have to be just one word, or would the idiom [keeping up with the times](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/change-with-keep-up-with-move-with-the-times) do?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually dozens of possibilities, depending on what, exactly, you want to say.

For example, there is FumbleFingers' suggestion of *adapt*.

> The video game giant Nintendo started as a playing card company, but quickly **adapted** to the growing interest in computer-based games.

Or Canadian Yankee's suggestion of *evolve* (which indicates a more gradual transition)

> The attitudes toward solar energy are constantly **evolving**.  What used to be seen as an environmentally-friendly-but-uneconomical choice for the fringe is now seen as a smart long-term investment.

Other possibilities, any of which can work depending on what you want to say:

> **acclimate** (slowly get used to something)
>
> **accommodate** (to make a change in order to satisfy some external condition)
>
> **conform** (change to match what others are doing)
>
> **revise** (make a change to something existing, in order to correct for an error or other factors)
>
> **tailor** (change to make "fit" a particular situation or use)
>
> **habituate** (slowly become comfortable with something, so that it feels natural)